# Summing absolute values using aggregate Excel

Tags: excel

I have a table with both negative, positive numbers and errors inside. Right now I'm using this function to get a total of all absolute values.

```
{=SUM(IF(ISERROR(C3:C28);0;ABS(C3:C28)))}}
```

Now I need a function that would do the same but only for rows that are not hidden (filtered). I have tried using subtotal and aggregate but they return #Value argument as you can't use them in an array.

```
{=AGGREGATE(9;7;ABS(C3:C28))}
```

Is it even possible to do it using a function or am I supposed to make additional column for absolute values and then sum using subtotal/aggregate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=SUMPRODUCT(ABS(C3:C28),SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(C3,ROW(C3:C28)-MIN(ROW(C3:C28)),0)))`

would be the usual approach, but based on your post I assume that `C3:C28` can contain error values, in which case an **array formula**** is required:

`=SUM(IF(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(C3,ROW(C3:C28)-MIN(ROW(C3:C28)),0)),ABS(C3:C28)))`

Regards